# Third Party API in Blackberry(JDE)

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

How to use third party api in blackberry jde ?....(I need send file to ftp server)

Comment: Do you have a third party API that will do this already?  If so you can make it a library and have your application use that or import it into your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the JAR file into the project - on the projects name, right click and select "Add file to project". With it added, you can import any of its libraries.

Another way is to make another project and set it to the library type. Add the JAR to it and and then you can add this project to your main project as a project dependancy. This works also but if you want to put your project on a real device, you need to first install the library project and then install your app.